# Add an image to a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky menu/floater bar when a user scrolls down on the page ... using jQuery I add the floater-bar class to the #menu-wrapper.

My goal is to add an image within an anchor at the same time floater-bar class is added so that the logo is on the floater bar as well.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $header_top_pos) {
  $("#menu-wrapper").addClass("floater-bar");
} else {
  $("#menu-wrapper").removeClass("floater-bar");
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
$("#menu-wrapper").append("<a href="#"><img src="image" /></a>");
```

Tried .add and .prepend as well

It makes the whole script fail as the floater-bar class no longer gets added into the menu.

Comment: Quotes are interrupting your append statement. Use single quotes within a double quoted string or escape the double quotes with `\"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
$("#menu-wrapper").append("<a href='#'><img src='image' /></a>");
```

You're using `"` to start and end the `append`, but then using it also to assign a `href` and the `src`, which is canceling out the string.

So only use `"` to start and end it, and if you need quotes inside, use `'`, or escape the double quotes by using `\"`.

If you wanted to do string concatenation (although not what you asked for, could come in handy later on), you do something like this:

```
$("#menu-wrapper").append("<a href='"+url+"'><img src='"+image+"' /></a>");
```

`image` and `url` would be variables. `+` is used to concatenate the string, giving you access to use variables within the string.

Comment: alternatively, you could escape the double quotes \" if you are a huge fan of the double quote

Comment: Just said that as you commented! Thanks @Huangism

Comment: Thank you guys for such quick response. I ended up having to escape the double quotes, the script itself is being called by a php variable therefore would break when i used single quote.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var anchor = $("a").attr("href","#");
var img = $("img").attr("src","img_source");
anchor.append(img);
$("#menu-wrapper").append(anchor);
```